# What’s the best way to connect 12 different SSDs—each already containing non-formatable, unique data—to my editing workstation?

Tags: video, ssd

We have a HP Z840 Windows 7 PC for video editing. Recently we recorded 4K video onto 24 SSD drives in the 4K Pro Res 422 format.

We need to connect up to 12 of these SSDs (12 cameras, with 1 drive per camera) into our editing station to edit simultaneously. Our sequences will have 6x 4K video footage being composed into a single sequence simultaneously.

What options do we have for connecting these drives to our workstation and eliminating the IO bottleneck (as much as possible)? The SSDs are already full of data and can't be re-formatted. Each drive is 1TB large.

Comment: I would just use a 12 disk JBOD enclosure over an eSATA connection.

Comment: as Ramhound said, a JBOD enclosure will allow to access each drive independently. Still, the single eSATA connection will be a bottleneck, so a RAID-card would be the best solution

Comment: Just to add to the conversation - we have already cloned the 24 SSDs to a hardware-RAID enclosure with 24TB of storage. However, working from this USB3.0 enclosure is a no-go, as the I/O bottleneck is huge.

Comment: One note here, a SATA v3 connection and a PCI express v3 "lane" have about the same bandwidth. For that combination a matched bandwidth would be about 20 sata ports to one 16 lane card. (ie plugs into a "video socket")  You would also need one monster of a machine to keep up.

Answer (score 2):

To get the greatest throughput, your going to want something hooked to the bus. I would recommend an add-in RAID card for SATA drives, [similar to this model](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0ZX2EC4925) which boasts 10 SATA connectors:

[image]

Don't RAID the drives together, just have individual volumes.

I've have no experience with that brand, but that single card could get you where you need to be for $800. General speaking, add-in RAID cards work great for this type of work. I would do a quick cruise on ebay to see if you can grab any used SATA-III RAID cards, and put them in multiple PCIE slots. 12x drives in an enclosure off of a single eSATA connector is definitely going to cause some bottlenecks.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, this card pictured could cause a performance bottleneck due to 10 cards sharing one PCIE slot. Your best option would be to go with 2 4-port cards, and if your motherboard can support it, plug the rest of the drives in directly.

I would count how many drive headers your motherboard has, add one for your OS drive, then subtract that from your total of 12 and buy the appropriately sized RAID board. Make sure you buy the correct type for your drives, SATA or SAS. SATA has individual connectors, SAS has one long connector.

[image]

Comment: @JakeGould It should still work. You can set almost any add-in RAID controller into JBOD-mode, where it will pass each drive to the operating system individually.

Comment: Just having lots of ports isn't enough -- the controller has to be fast enough to handle delivering the data to the workstation.

Comment: True, I just pointed out that card because it had many ports. I would be likely to choose 2 four port cards with good controllers, and make up the difference with motherboard ports.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to set a few SATA adapter cards as your SATA controller likely can't handle all of those drives at once.  You could use SATA multipliers but that distributes the bandwidth, resulting in slower throughput of data.  RAID cards are typically more expensive than SATA adapter cards.  If you are not going to be setting up a RAID, you should use a SATA adapter.